# Share an object over multiple processes

Tags: eclipse, python-3.x, pydev

## Goal

I want to share an object with multiple processes. The Object has a list with method references. Each process should check for work in the List and process it.

## Problem

As soon as I share the object the list gets empty

## Code

```
###manager.BlockNet.py:###
import manager.BlockNetProcess
from multiprocessing import queues
class blockmgr():
    WAITLIST=[]
    kill=False
    def __init__(self,):
        pass
    def adJob(self,job):
        if not job in self.WAITLIST:
            self.WAITLIST.append(job)
    def getJob(self):
        j=self.WAITLIST.pop(0)
        return j
    def __empty(self,id):
        print('empty')
    def startProcesses(self,mgr,number=8):
        self.qeue=queues.Queue()
        self.queue.put(mgr)
        result=manager.BlockNetProcess.start(q,number)
        return result
```

mgr is the object I want to share between all processes

```
 ###manager.BlockNetProcess.py:###
    from multiprocessing import pool,queues
    def worker(q):
        '''this is the method each process executes'''
        print('start Worker')
        mgr=q.get()
        while not mgr.kill:
            mgr=q.get()
            job=mgr.getJob()
            print(job)
            #job[0](job[1])
        return []
    def start(q,number):
        for i in range(number):
            p = pool.Pool(processes=1)
            result=p.apply_async(worker,[q])
        return result
```

After starting the processes I get an error because I cann not pop from a list if it's empty. But I've added thing to the list before calling the  `startProcesses` Method.
Where is my mistake? Or is there a better Method to exchange Objects between processes?